# while loop with a timed condition doesn't terminate

Tags: c++, time, struct, while-loop, initialization

I'm doing a homework problem involving local search. I'd like to restart the search using a new initial state after some time. For this I included a time condition in my while loop.

```
void run_local_search()
{
    while (time(NULL) - timer < (tim * 60) - 1) // tim is some user defined time in minutes. I've initialized timer in my main function right before calling the run_local_search().
    {
        struct state initial; // Declaring the initial state structure

        start_state(&initial); // Generates a random starting state.
        if (initial.profit > best.profit)
        {
            best = initial;
        }
        local_search(&initial);
    }
}
```

My main local search function is

```
void local_search(state* s)
{
    clock_t searchtime; 
    searchtime = clock(); // I initialize the clock right before the search loop here
    while ((clock() - searchtime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC < 2) // I want the loop to run for 2 seconds
    {...}
    cout << "Done" << endl;
}
```

I discovered that the struct state initial; statement doesn't reinitialize the initial struct across iterations of the while loop. The same value for initial carries on in a new iteration of the while loop so my start_state function which generates a random value is rendered useless! How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Show us the `tim` and `timer`, and as mentioned by @OliCharlesworth it's best to have minimal self sufficient examples.

Comment: Hi! I added print statements (I haven't shown them in the code), and I've isolated the problem to be related to how the struct (struct state initial;) is initialized in the while loop. It appears to keep a persistent value across iterations of the loop. How do I make sure that the value of the struct can be redeclared and reinitialized?

Answer (score 0):

From the little info you gave I can guess about the algorithm is to be initialized once, *before* the tim minute loop:

```
void run_local_search(){
  struct state initial;
  //     start_state(&initial);   //moved into loop
  while (time(NULL) - timer < (tim * 60) - 1){
    start_state(&initial);
    if (initial.profit > best.profit){
        best = initial;
    }
    local_search(&initial);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd like the struct state initial; statement to be kept in the loop so that the start_state function can be run again (it generates a random starting state each time). But when I keep it in the loop, the 'initial' state has a persistent value across iterations of the while loop.

Comment: @krandiash Then, maybe, just the struct state initial; should be outside, see edited proposal.